# Why nothing taken from n things can have 1 permutation?

Tags: permutations

Without repeating if I take 0 thing out of n, how the permutation will be 1 (**nP0 = 1**)? And what will be that permutation? 
Even allowing repetition, the result is 1 (**n^0 = 1**)?

**How is the permutation 1 and what is that permutation?**

Answer (score 1):

Just as there is exactly one subset of any set that has no elements—namely, the empty set—there is exactly one ordered selection of any set that has no elements—namely, the empty selection.

Comment: We say that **selecting** 0 elements out of n, but the result is **empty selection**?!
Why?

Comment: The empty selection is the selection with nothing in it. There is exactly one selection which is empty.